# What downvoted questions on SO, or Programmers.SE are worth looking at (for non-Meta reasons)?

Tags: discussion, badges, down-votes, populist-badge, reversal-badge

Are there any downvoted questions on Stack Overflow (or Programmers) that are worth looking at for non-meta reasons?

To see where I'm going with this, think along the lines of the Populist and Reversal badge. If you click on that badge you see a list of interesting answers.

The intent of this question is to dig out information that are borderline Populist and Reversal, but are not "extreme" enough to be listed under the badge itself. As it is today, those questions are essentially hidden from view.

Comment: You could create a [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) query to pull out those posts. Start with the actual thresholds that will qualify for the badges, then relax them a little and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/867/good-answers-to-bad-questions-that-dont-qualify-for-the-reversal-badge).

Comment: Cool! Thanks, now that will help through filtering through them